tx.from.Store in types.Sender does not leave, CPU 100%
This is a follow up of this post. I nailed it down to the code in the official sync atomic Store() procedure, called by geths types.Sender function.
In short, in rare cases Store() never leaves, and the CPU is at 100%. I guess it is the for {} loop and those continues in it (see code here )
Does anyone has an idea what can cause this? How is this possible since this is an official module?

Can you provide a small reproducible example?

After looking at the code why are you calling Store()? If you really needed it I'd separate the sender calculation from other processing. The random error might indicate some kind of async issue.
